# Xubuntu show me two audio interfaces and I only have one

Tags: ubuntu, audio, pulseaudio

I've been looking about this issue but all I find is related to using two different outputs for audio, but my problem is a bit different.

Out of the blue my xubuntu now shows me 2 "built-in audio" interfaces, and every time I play something (it doesn't matter if it's from VLC, Firefox, Olive..) I have to keep switching between these two interfaces until I get audio output in my speakers or headphone. I'm using pulseaudio, BTW.

Can anyone think of why this is happening? I didn't loaded any kernel module manually.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me. I was able to turn off the second audio interface using PulseAudio Volume Control. In the configuration tab I was able to turn it off by selecting an "off" profile.
I don't know why it started though.